# Is it possible to lock down the http / https proxy settings on an iPhone?

Tags: tls, ios, iphone, http-proxy, squid

Is there any way to lock down the [proxy settings](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/144427/configure-https-proxy-on-ipad) on an iPhone so that they can't be changed by anyone but the person with the password?

Comment: I searched around after your initial post, and could not find a mechanism to do this. There are mechanisms to restrict specifics (http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/lock-childs-iphone-access-hide-apps-ios-restrictions/) but nothing related to proxies. Unless someone posts a solution, you may want to look into a Mobile Device Management system (e.g. https://github.com/project-imas/mdm-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configuration 2 has an option specifically for a HTTP Global Proxy. You will need to get it on the Mac app store (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12).

Once you've downloaded that, create a new profile with the HTTP Global Proxy, sign it, and add it to your iDevice.

See this link for more information https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4359121?tstart=0